# Node.js + Socket.io + Windows 10?

Tags: node.js

Здраствуйте. Столкнулся впервые с `node.js`(установка и использование сокетов). Проблема в том,что при установке любого пакета типа `npm install` выдает одно и тоже предупреждение `npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`. Понимаю что настройки системы не устраивают. Подскажите куда копать чтобы исправить. Или вся проблема в виндовсе в корне? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не поверите, но ничего делать не надо. Это [опциональный пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) для работы со специфическими API  OS X. Он просто недоступен для Windows и это нормально ([вот здесь](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/issues/165) есть похожий вопрос в гитхабе проекта).

Comment: Спасибо,хотя этого я и боялся. Но в моем случае есть альтернативные варианты?Я теже сокеты заинсталить не могу просто)

Comment: Вообще, если вы не можете установить какой-то из пакетов, то проблема скорее всего не в этом ворнинге., он носит исключительно информативный характер. Киньте ссылку, какой именно пакет Вы не можете установить?

Comment: npm install express ioredis socket.io --save. Это то что мне как раз нужно. но и на остальные ворнинг тот же

Comment: Только что попробовал сделать npm install express ioredis socket.io --save на чистом проекте -- всё прошло удачно, все пакеты добавились. Версия npm 5.0.3, "express": "^4.15.3", "ioredis": "^3.1.1", "socket.io": "^2.0.3". Даже ворнига о fsevents не выдало, хотя я точно его видел раньше на прошлых проектах. При этом несмотря на ворнинг, все пакеты добавлялись успешно.

Comment: странно. А файл socket.io.js был сформирован? Спасибо

Comment: Не совсем так, но да. В папке node_modules появились подпапки socket.io, socket.io-adapter, socket.io-client и socket.io-parser. Вот, первая и содержит основные модули для импорта.

Comment: @hambit7 Вы устанавливаете на чистом проекте?

Comment: На ларавел,если вы это имеете в виду